# On Certain Characteristic Function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find the characteristic function for Johnson's SU distribution by integrating the probability density function with `Exp[I*t*x]` but Mathematica is returning the input itself.

As the characteristic function always exists, I'm not able to understand why Mathematica is not finding the integral.

Here's the code:

```
expr1[x_] := PDF[JohnsonDistribution["SU", γ, δ, ξ, λ], 
  x]

Integrate[expr1[x]*Exp[I*t*x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Comment: @m_goldberg Closing a question from a first timer *abruptly* may alienate the person from this forum and worse: from the Wolfram community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at [the characteristic function of the lognormal distribution.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CharacteristicFunction.html) 
In some cases there is no closed form.
One way to address this issue is using empirical' s one.

```
emCF = With[{dist = #}, 
    RandomVariate[dist, 100] // Exp[I t #] & /@ # & // Mean // 
     Set[approx, #] &;
    ReIm[approx]] &;
```

> #### approximated characteristic function of NormalDistribution[0,1]

```
Plot[Evaluate[emCF[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]], {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> #### exact characteristic function of NormalDistribution[0,1]

```
Plot[ReIm@CharacteristicFunction[NormalDistribution[0, 1], t], {t, -1,
   1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> #### approximated characteristic function of JohnsonDistribution["SU", a, b, c, d]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[emCF[JohnsonDistribution["SU", a, b, c, d]]], {t, -1, 
   1}], {a, -5, 5}, {b, 0.01, 5}, {c, -5, 5}, {d, 0.01, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

The first assignment is incorrect, resp. I don't know what it should mean from a Wolfram Mathematica syntax perspective. It can mean

expression: a correct form is

```
 expr1 = PDF[JohnsonDistribution["SU", γ, δ, ξ, λ], x]
```

or function definition: a correct form is

```
 expr1[x_] := PDF[JohnsonDistribution["SU", γ, δ, ξ, λ], x]
```

However, I think that this is not a major issue. It is that apparently the characteristic function for Johnson's distribution cannot be expressed in the form of a closed expression. Neither wikipedia nor other source know the formula for general characteristic function. The Mathematica answer is "I'm not able to calculate it", i.e.

```
 CharacteristicFunction[JohnsonDistribution["SU", γ, δ, ξ, λ], t]
```

> `CharacteristicFunction[JohnsonDistribution["SU", γ, δ, ξ, λ], t]`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the function definition as supplied. It simply uses immediate evaluation instead of delayed. The real answer is your second portion to this.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Exactly right. Function assignments of the form `f[x_] = ...` are simply equivalent to `f[x_] := Evaluate[...]`.